useEffect hook is called twice when the component mounts
Being working on a MERN application which uses Vite as the front end going with React. I have used the useEffect hook to fetch the data from the database where the data is listed inside a table. There are no errors or warning in the console but when I console log it seems that the useEffect hook is called twice when the page is refreshed.
Below is my code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const OperatingSites = () => {
  const [siteData, setSiteData] = useState([
    { location: '', type: '', address: '' } 
  ]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/operatingSite');
        const fetchData = response.data;
        setSiteData([...fetchData, { location: '', type: '', address: '' }]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
      
    };

    console.log("UseEffect");
    
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  const handleInputChange = (index, event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newData = [...siteData];
    newData[index][name] = value;
    setSiteData(newData);

    // Automatically add a new row if editing the last row and it's not empty
    if (index === newData.length - 1 && newData[index].location && newData[index].type && newData[index].address) {
      addEmptyRow();
    }
  };

  const addEmptyRow = () => {
    setSiteData([...siteData, { location: '', type: '', address: '' }]);
  };

  const generateRows = () => {
    return siteData.map((site, index) => (
        
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="w-full border-none focus:ring-transparent text-center"
            placeholder="Enter location"
            name="location"
            value={site.location}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(index, e)}
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <select
            className="w-full border-none focus:ring-transparent text-center"
            name="type"
            value={site.type}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(index, e)}
          >
            <option value="">Choose...</option>
            <option value="Primary">Primary</option>
            <option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="w-full border-none focus:ring-transparent text-center"
            placeholder="Enter address"
            name="address"
            value={site.address}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(index, e)}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const filteredData = siteData.filter(site => site.location && site.type && site.address);
    try {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/operatingSite', filteredData);
      alert('Data submitted successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting data:', error);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="flex">
      
      <div className="w-full pb-20 pt-8 pr-28 pl-28">
        <div className="relative overflow-hidden ">
          <table className="w-full text-center  border border-[#52B14A] ">
            <thead className="bg-[#00bdf6] h-10">
              <tr>
                <th className="py-2">Location</th>
                <th className="py-2">Primary/Secondary</th>
                <th className="py-2">Address</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="bg-transparent ">
              {generateRows()}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="mt-4 p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white">
            Submit Changes
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OperatingSites;


As you can see I have a console log inside the hook to check when it's been called:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const OperatingSites = () => {
  const [siteData, setSiteData] = useState([
    { location: '', type: '', address: '' } 
  ]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/operatingSite');
        const fetchData = response.data;
        setSiteData([...fetchData, { location: '', type: '', address: '' }]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
      
    };

    console.log("UseEffect");
    
    fetchData();
  }, []);


and the console output would be:
enter image description here
The problem is, useEffect is triggered twice when I check with console.log. The code is thus querying the same data twice, which should be avoided. This doesn't affect the project as there is no error but I would like to know the particular reason behind  useEffect running twice when the component mounts.

Are you using React's strict mode?

Most probably you have React StrictMode on.
Please check if your app is surrounded with the tag <StrictMode>. Strict Mode renders components twice (on dev but not production) in order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them (which can be quite useful). This is expected behavior.
